# PHP web sessions

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have couple questions regarding the sessions ...

1) How can I list all active sessions on my server?

2) How can I make secure login, account timeout and logout using sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's default session handler saves the session data as a `serialize()` copy of the $_SESSION array, and that goes into a file, which is specified in php.ini. You can retrieve it at runtime with `session_save_path()`. Generally, the files are constructed as

```
$sessionFile = 'sess_' . session_id();
```

Listing all sessions is just a matter of pulling out all the files in the session dir that start with `sess_`. However, unless you're doing long-running processes, most sessions will only be 'active' for the short time someone's actually hitting a page on your site.

As for the login system, there's tons of answers on this site. Look at the "Related" links on the right-hand side of this page to find some.

Comment: @Marc B: can you explain more about the session list? I`m running my own server (localhost) on which I can access from any PC over the LAN. I want to show the session of each access.

Comment: each access? You mean look in the server's access log?

Comment: usually when I access a website, a session is created for my access. I want to preview this (as admin) on my localhost/testing server.

Comment: PHP doesn't create sessions automatically unless it's configured to do so.  `session.auto_start` in php.ini, or via `session_start()` calls in your code.

Comment: OK, I use session_start() what can I do as admin page that lists all the sessions and delete the ones I don`t want them to be connected?

Comment: very simplest: `chdir(session_save_dir()); print_r(glob('*'));`